# conversion snipset code in jquery to dojo - ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dojo

i need to change my code in jquery to dojo. The objective is only a snipset equivalent.

The jquery code works fine but the dojo code no.

JQUERY

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".box").change(function() {
            $.ajax({
                dataType: 'json',
                type: "POST",
                data: "data=" + $(this).val(),
                url: "file.php",
                success: function(json) {
                    $msg = [];

                    for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
                        $msg.push(parseFloat(json[i]["valor" + i]));
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

DOJO

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
dojo.query(".box").onchange(function() {
    dojo.xhrGet({
        url: "file.php",
        handleAs: "json",
        data: "data=" + $(this).val(),
        load: function(json) {
            $msg = [];

            for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
                $msg.push(parseFloat(json[i]["valor" + i]));
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.query(".box").onchange(function() {
        dojo.xhrPost({
            url:"drop2.php",
            handleAs:"json",
            postData: "data=" + $(this).val(),
            preventCache: true,
            load: function(json){
                 $msg = [];

                 for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
                     $msg.push(parseFloat(json[i]["valor" + i]));
                 }
            }
        });
    }); 


    </script>
```